# Plinko how to direct the ball in the most natural way to go to the last multiplier with the path defined before

Tags: reactjs, matter.js

Currently I'm working on a plinko game using `matterjs` and `react`. I don't know how to direct the ball in the most natural way like plinko game on [bc.game](https://bc.game/game/plinko). I just can do like the example in [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/metter-pixi-plinko-forked-sqnhkp). In bcgame, the ball always collides more than two times in one row, and when the path includes a `reversed direction` the ball will collide in another way (but still make sure to go with the correct path). But in the example link, the ball only collides one time in each row (it is like fake animation from the user's expectation).

I had researched for two weeks on the internet but I still can not complete this one. Hope anyone can help me. Please!!!

*Almost plinko game will have a result path like `[1,0,0,1,1,1,0]`, `0 is left`, and `1 is right`*